# Web scraping content of ::before ::after using python returns [ ]

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pseudo-element

I am super new to python, even coding as a whole. I have successfully scraped about 10 websites using this code, but all of a sadden it does not work with this website. I want to extract all divs with class of each product. but the divs dont show up in the page_soup. I read that about the ::before and ::after being a problem but I cant find solution that works. I might have multiple problems in my code, but I cant find them. I have had 2 weeks of sleepless nights. please help

```
from urllib.request import  urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.woolworths.co.za/cat?No=60&Nrpp=60&Ns=p_pl30|0"

uClient=uReq(url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")
containers=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"product-list__item"})
print(containers)
        
quit()
```

result I get
[ ]

let me know if I must provide more information

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with `::before` / `::after` - you are not getting results because the page is loading the content dynamically and your divs are not on the page as of fetching it.

Comment: I dont know what to do, I tried waiting for page to load using time(), any idea how I can get the div

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded externally via sending a `GET` request and adding the correct `headers` to:

```
https://www.woolworths.co.za/server/searchCategory?pageURL=%2Fcat&No=60&Nrpp=60&Ns=p_pl30%7C0
```

You can get the data using just the `requests` module, there's no need to use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests


headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.woolworths.co.za/cat?No=60&Nrpp=60&Ns=p_pl30|0",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36",
}

URL = "https://www.woolworths.co.za/server/searchCategory?pageURL=%2Fcat&No=60&Nrpp=60&Ns=p_pl30%7C0"
response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers).json()
fmt_string = "{:<70} {:<15} {}"

print(fmt_string.format("Brand", "Price", "Image"))
print("-" * 200)

for d in response["contents"][0]["mainContent"][0]["contents"]:
    for dd in d["records"]:
        print(
            fmt_string.format(
                dd["attributes"]["p_displayName"],
                dd["startingPrice"]["p_pl30"],
                "https://images.woolworthsstatic.co.za/"
                + dd["attributes"]["p_externalImageReference"],
            )
        )
```

Output (truncated):

```
Brand                                                                  Price           Image
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Soda Water Sparkling Drink 200 ml                                      9.49            https://images.woolworthsstatic.co.za/Soda-Water-Sparkling-Drink-200-ml-6001009034250.jpg?V=50$J&o=eucyUmAbqcqMSs0IjPaS4WA$mzoj&
Salt & Vinegar Flavoured Potato Crisps 36 g                            9.49            https://images.woolworthsstatic.co.za/Salt-Vinegar-Flavoured-Potato-Crisps-36-g-6009175413541.jpg?V=6Pfl&o=Tyz@wbWHKvnW@Kc69RTJYM7WBUQj&
Salted Farmer's Crisps 36 g                                            9.49            https://images.woolworthsstatic.co.za/Salted-Farmer-s-Crisps-36-g-6009217630752.jpg?V=TM2n&o=eR0n3eqV0@15TKcRSRz1RzzVPW8j&
Lemonade Sugar Free Sparkling Flavoured Drink 200 ml                   9.49            https://images.woolworthsstatic.co.za/Lemonade-Sugar-Free-Sparkling-Flavoured-Drink-200-ml-6001009014238.jpg?V=9Skb&o=hqcUN6THi9J8YRixCQEica2ftcMj&
Ginger Ale Sugar Free Sparkling Flavoured Drink 200 ml                 9.49            https://images.woolworthsstatic.co.za/Ginger-Ale-Sugar-Free-Sparkling-Flavoured-Drink-200-ml-6001009014245.jpg?V=x9Pr&o=C7oKpoX27D3z2vf11X7bKRmUJEsj&
Cheddar Flavoured Crisps 36 g                                          9.49            https://images.woolworthsstatic.co.za/Cheddar-Flavoured-Crisps-36-g-6009217630776.jpg?V=zCPn&o=Ufn3jhhUzUGckf72QHLRaa64g20j&
...
```

Comment: thanks guyz. this is great, thanks.I managed to get the brand also, but how do I get the price and image

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works very well. You guyz are the best

Comment: @Vally Glad to help. If this or any answer has solved your problem, consider marking it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)